# Regex look-behind without obvious maximum length in Java

Tags: java, regex

I always thought that a *look-behind* assertion in Java's regex-API (and many other languages for that matter) must have an obvious length. So, STAR and PLUS quantifiers are not allowed inside *look-behinds*.

The excellent online resource [regular-expressions.info](http://regular-expressions.info) seems to confirm (some of) my assumptions:

> "[...] Java takes things a step further by
>   allowing finite repetition. You still
>   cannot use the star or plus, but you
>   can use the question mark and the
>   curly braces with the max parameter
>   specified. Java recognizes the fact
>   that finite repetition can be
>   rewritten as an alternation of strings
>   with different, but fixed lengths.
>   Unfortunately, the JDK 1.4 and 1.5
>   have some bugs when you use
>   alternation inside lookbehind. These
>   were fixed in JDK 1.6. [...]"
>
> -- http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Using the curly brackets works as long as the total length of range of the characters inside the look-behind is smaller or equal to Integer.MAX_VALUE. So these regexes are valid:

```
"(?<=a{0,"   +(Integer.MAX_VALUE)   + "})B"
"(?<=Ca{0,"  +(Integer.MAX_VALUE-1) + "})B"
"(?<=CCa{0," +(Integer.MAX_VALUE-2) + "})B"
```

But these aren't:

```
"(?<=Ca{0,"  +(Integer.MAX_VALUE)   +"})B"
"(?<=CCa{0," +(Integer.MAX_VALUE-1) +"})B"
```

However, I don't understand the following:

When I run a test using the * and + quantifier inside a *look-behind*, all goes well (see output **Test 1** and **Test 2**).

But, when I add a single character at the start of the *look-behind* from **Test 1** and **Test 2**, it breaks (see output **Test 3**).

Making the greedy * from **Test 3** reluctant has no effect, it still breaks (see **Test 4**).

Here's the test harness:

```
public class Main {

    private static String testFind(String regex, String input) {
        try {
            boolean returned = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input).find();
            return "testFind       : Valid   -> regex = "+regex+", input = "+input+", returned = "+returned;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            return "testFind       : Invalid -> "+regex+", "+e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    private static String testReplaceAll(String regex, String input) {
        try {
            String returned = input.replaceAll(regex, "FOO");
            return "testReplaceAll : Valid   -> regex = "+regex+", input = "+input+", returned = "+returned;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            return "testReplaceAll : Invalid -> "+regex+", "+e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    private static String testSplit(String regex, String input) {
        try {
            String[] returned = input.split(regex);
            return "testSplit      : Valid   -> regex = "+regex+", input = "+input+", returned = "+java.util.Arrays.toString(returned);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            return "testSplit      : Invalid -> "+regex+", "+e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] regexes = {"(?<=a*)B", "(?<=a+)B", "(?<=Ca*)B", "(?<=Ca*?)B"};
        String input = "CaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaBaaaa";
        int test = 0;
        for(String regex : regexes) {
            test++;
            System.out.println("********************** Test "+test+" **********************");
            System.out.println("    "+testFind(regex, input));
            System.out.println("    "+testReplaceAll(regex, input));
            System.out.println("    "+testSplit(regex, input));
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

The output:

```
********************** Test 1 **********************
    testFind       : Valid   -> regex = (?<=a*)B, input = CaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaBaaaa, returned = true
    testReplaceAll : Valid   -> regex = (?<=a*)B, input = CaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaBaaaa, returned = CaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaFOOaaaa
    testSplit      : Valid   -> regex = (?<=a*)B, input = CaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaBaaaa, returned = [Caaaaaaaaaaaaaaa, aaaa]

********************** Test 2 **********************
    testFind       : Valid   -> regex = (?<=a+)B, input = CaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaBaaaa, returned = true
    testReplaceAll : Valid   -> regex = (?<=a+)B, input = CaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaBaaaa, returned = CaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaFOOaaaa
    testSplit      : Valid   -> regex = (?<=a+)B, input = CaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaBaaaa, returned = [Caaaaaaaaaaaaaaa, aaaa]

********************** Test 3 **********************
    testFind       : Invalid -> (?<=Ca*)B, Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length near index 6
(?<=Ca*)B
      ^
    testReplaceAll : Invalid -> (?<=Ca*)B, Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length near index 6
(?<=Ca*)B
      ^
    testSplit      : Invalid -> (?<=Ca*)B, Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length near index 6
(?<=Ca*)B
      ^

********************** Test 4 **********************
    testFind       : Invalid -> (?<=Ca*?)B, Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length near index 7
(?<=Ca*?)B
       ^
    testReplaceAll : Invalid -> (?<=Ca*?)B, Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length near index 7
(?<=Ca*?)B
       ^
    testSplit      : Invalid -> (?<=Ca*?)B, Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length near index 7
(?<=Ca*?)B
       ^
```

My question may be obvious, but I'll still ask it: *Can anyone explain to me why **Test 1** and **2** fail, and **Test 3** and **4** don't?* I would have expected them all to fail, not half of them to work and half of them to fail.

Thanks.

PS. I'm using: Java version 1.6.0_14

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Glancing at the source code for Pattern.java reveals that the '*' and '+' are implemented as instances of Curly (which is the object created for curly operators). So,

```
a*
```

is implemented as

```
a{0,0x7FFFFFFF}
```

and

```
a+
```

is implemented as

```
a{1,0x7FFFFFFF}
```

which is why you see exactly the same behaviors for curlies and stars.

Comment: It didn't occur to me to look at the source of Pattern... Silly me. Thank you! It makes perfect sense now.

Comment: One of the many reasons I can't live without Eclipse is my itchy ctrl-click finger (which, if you don't use Eclipse, means "open up the source file where this name is defined").

Comment: Thanks, I've never taken the trouble to attach the source to Eclipse. I will do so now for sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

It's a bug: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6695369

`Pattern.compile()` is always supposed to throw an exception if it can't determine the maximum possible length of a lookbehind match.

Comment: Hey Alan, figured you'd come along soon! Thanks, I knew this used to be a bug (in 1.5) but I remembered that the engine always evaluated to false or something. Now it does evaluate the result correctly, so I figured the bug got fixed in 1.6. I must've remembered incorrectly. Thanks for the info.

Bart (aka prometheuzz)

Comment: That bug got fixed; this is a new one that was introduced in 1.6. :/

Comment: Link should now be [https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6695369](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6695369) -- tried to edit it in but the edit queue is apparently full.

Comment: @GavinS.Yancey, I fixed it.

Comment: It's now https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6695369