# Splitting string N into N/X strings

Tags: java, regex, string, split, math

I would like some guidance on how to split a string into N number of separate strings based on a arithmetical operation; for example string.length()/300.

I am aware of ways to do it with delimiters such as

```
testString.split(",");
```

but how does one uses greedy/reluctant/possessive quantifiers with the `split` method?

---

**Update:** As per request a similar example of what am looking to achieve;

```
String X = "32028783836295C75546F7272656E745C756E742E657865000032002E002E005C0"
```

Resulting in X/3 *(more or less... done by hand)*

```
X[0] = 32028783836295C75546F

X[1] = 6E745C756E742E6578650

x[2] = 65000032002E002E005C0
```

Dont worry about explaining how to put it into the array, I have no problem with that, only on how to split without using a delimiter, but an arithmetic operation

Comment: Could you be more specific ? It would help if you give an example of what you want.

Comment: @hal: done the update, thanks for the interest!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do that by splitting on `(?<=\G.{5})` whereby the string `aaaaabbbbbccccceeeeefff` would be split into the following parts:

```
aaaaa
bbbbb
ccccc
eeeee
fff
```

The `\G` matches the (zero-width) position where the previous match occurred. Initially, `\G` starts at the beginning of the string. Note that by default the `.` meta char does not match line breaks, so if you want it to match every character, enable DOT-ALL: `(?s)(?<=\G.{5})`.

A demo:

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int N = 5;
    String text = "aaaaabbbbbccccceeeeefff";
    String[] tokens = text.split("(?<=\\G.{" + N + "})");
    for(String t : tokens) {
      System.out.println(t);
    }
  }
}
```

which can be tested online here: http://ideone.com/q6dVB

**EDIT**

Since you asked for documentation on regex, here are the specific tutorials for the topics the suggested regex contains:

- `\G`, see: http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html
- `(?<=...)`, see: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html
- `{...}`, see: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Comment: thanks again, hey! great site by the way to give examples. Take it easy

Comment: @Bart; if i may ask, could you let me know of any website u may know where i could learn this further, u seem to be very familiar with it, from ur answer and question :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536915/regex-look-behind-without-obvious-maximum-length-in-java

Comment: @Carlucho, if you're real serious, you need the book [Mastering Regular Expressions](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565922570) on your book-shelf. It is **the** book on regular expressions. As for online references, there are probably a lot of decent ones around, but this one is definitely in the top 5: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: @Bart Kiers, buddy could you explain me a little further what each of the characters does in this regex. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If there's a fixed length that you want each `String` to be, you can use [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com)'s [Splitter](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html):

```
int length = string.length() / 300;
Iterable<String> splitStrings = Splitter.fixedLength(length).split(string);
```

Each `String` in `splitStrings` with the possible exception of the last will have a length of `length`. The last may have a length between 1 and `length`.

Note that unlike `String.split`, which first builds an `ArrayList<String>` and then uses `toArray()` on that to produce the final `String[]` result, Guava's `Splitter` is lazy and doesn't do anything with the input string when `split` is called. The actual splitting and returning of strings is done as you iterate through the resulting `Iterable`. This allows you to just iterate over the results without allocating a data structure and storing them all or to copy them into any kind of `Collection` you want without going through the intermediate `ArrayList` and `String[]`. Depending on what you want to do with the results, this can be considerably more efficient. It's also *much* more clear what you're doing than with a regex.

Answer (score 2):

How about plain old String.substring? It's memory friendly (as it reuses the original char array).

Answer (score 1):

Dunno, you'll probably need a method that takes string and int times and returns a list of strings. Pseudo code (haven't checked if it works or not):

```
public String[] splintInto(String splitString, int parts)
{
   int dlength = splitString.length/parts
   ArrayList<String> retVal = new ArrayList<String>()
   for(i=0; i<splitString.length;i+=dlength)
   {
      retVal.add(splitString.substring(i,i+dlength)

   }
   return retVal.toArray()
}
```

Comment: hmm not sure about this `add` business

Comment: No, an array does not have methods in Java.

Comment: I did said, pseudo code. And that is mostly a remnant of programming in Fantom where arrays have add.

Answer (score 1):

well, I think this is probably as efficient a way to do this as any other.

```
int N=300;
int sublen = testString.length()/N;
String[] subs = new String[N];
for(int i=0; i<testString.length(); i+=sublen){
  subs[i] = testString.substring(i,i+sublen);
}
```

You can do it faster if you need the items as a `char[]` array rather as individual `Strings` - depending on how you need to use the results - e.g. using `testString.toCharArray()`