# RegEx for HTML replace

Tags: java, regex, replace

Hi I am trying to find RegEx which helps me to replace words in HTML. Problem occurs if the word i am trying to replace is in HTML tag as well.
Example:`<img class="TEST">asd TEST asd dsa asd </img>`
and i need to get the second "TEST" only.

RegEx i am looking for should look like `>[^<]*TEST`, but this regex takes chars before the word TEST as well. Is it possible to select only word TEST ? but imagine other combinations as well (i dont think " TEST " is a good solution as soon as text could contain another chars as well)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: This is a job for a parser. Do a search for: "java html parser" and you will be on your way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, like has been said and will be said again, using regex for XML is usually a bad idea.  But for really simple cases it can work, especially if you can live with sub-optimal results.

So, just put the test in a group and replace only the group

Something like

```
Pattern replacePattern = Pattern.compile(">[^<]*(TEST)");
Matcher matcher = replacePattern.matcher(theString);
String result = theString.substr(1,matcher.start(1)) + replacement + theString.substr(matcher.end(1));
```

Disclaimer: Not tested, might have some off-by-ones.  But the concept should be clear.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, regex is not good option for html parsing.. There are lots of enhanced html parsers that you can use..

But if you insist to use regex , here is the regex ;

```
(?<=>.*)TEST(?=.*<)
```

for java,

```
(?<=>.{0,100000})TEST(?=.{0,100000}<)
```

for more information why we can not use * or + with lookbehind regex in Java , [Regex look-behind without obvious maximum length in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536915/regex-look-behind-without-obvious-maximum-length-in-java)

Comment: i am not parsing whole html, for that i use Jericho. I just wanted easy way of replacing some words. I cant make your regex working ...testing here http://myregexp.com/

Comment: I like your solution, but  not working for code like this:
`<p> [newLine here]
TEST [newLine here]
</p>`

Answer (score 0):

How about if "TEST" is inside another tag than , like say inside the body tag, or for that matter inside the html tag?

Comment: ahh maybe i said it wrong way. i mean between '<' and '>'. it is okey if word is inside tag <> here </>, not ok if its < here>.