# Remove trailing decimal point & zeroes with Regex

Tags: java, regex, string

Is this the proper REGEX to remove trailing decimal and zeroes from a string? I can't get it to work. What am I missing?

1. 78.000 -> 78
2. 78.008 -> 78.008

`str.replaceAll("^.0*$", "");`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to escape the `.`, as it is a special character in Regex that matches any character. You also have to remove the `^`, which anchors at the beginning of the number.

```
str.replaceAll("\\.0*$", "");
```

You can use a lookbehind if you want to make sure there is a number in front of the dot, like this:

```
str.replaceAll("(?<=^\\d+)\\.0*$", "");
```

The lookbehind (the `(?<=...)` part) is not a part of the match, so it will not be replaced, but it still has to match for the rest of the regex to match.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but your lookbehind wont work - Java requires lookbehinds to have a maximum length, so you can't use `+` or `*` inside them. Also, you should probably improve the wording of that last sentence - a lookbehind _can_ be part of a match, it's simply that it matches a position not a character (and in this case that position is before the match). It is possible to do stuff like `str.replaceAll("(?<=whatever)","stuff")` to append text after a match.

Comment: @PeterBoughton, it seems to work fine [here](http://ideone.com/aBhHS). Are you sure about the lookbehind part?

Comment: Hmm. I _was_ sure - I'm always forgetting and running into this problem, and having to switch to `{0,99}` or `{1,99}` instead. Now I'm confused. :/

Comment: @PeterBoughton, I looked it up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536915/regex-look-behind-without-obvious-maximum-length-in-java . Apparently, the match in the lookbehind has to be shorter than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Also, `+` is implemented as `{1,0x7FFFFFFF}`. Thus, since there is only one character in the lookbehind (`\d`), it will work. But if I add one more, like [here](http://ideone.com/JcHGw) it fails.

Comment: Ok, well I'm not going crazy, but I don't know what's up either...

Doing `\d*` works. Doing `\d+` works. Doing `\d\d*` throws the error "Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length near index 8"

http://ideone.com/6mRfk

Comment: Ah, just seen that comment after I submitted mine... that at least explains the behaviour. Wish it could be smarter and just limit the whole lookbehind to MAX_VALUE, no matter how many characters/quantifiers it contained.

Comment: It's because the maximum possible length of the lookbehind exceeds `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. `\d*` has the maximum length of `0x7FFFFFFF`, or `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. If you add another `\d`, it becomes `Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1`, and you have an error.

Comment: Yeah, I understand now - I was simply saying it'd be nice if it detected/avoided that error and limited the `\d*` to `0x7FFFFFFF - [length of fixed portion]`. Meh.

Comment: This is all great discussion - thank you all! Especially the example, thanks @Harpyon.

Comment: Does not handle 1.230->1.23

Answer (score 5):

Nope. Use this:

```
str.replaceAll("[.0]+$", "");
```

Comment: This is not quite right, since it would cause something like `2.000.000` to be converted to `2`

Comment: @NullUserException ఠ_ఠ - Well, isn't that what the OP wants?

Comment: Maybe. The way I interpreted it, this should be converted to `2.000`

Comment: It would need to be converted to 2. Thank you!

Comment: @FelixYan - True. We're not building a spaceship here. We're solving the OP's question, which was always dealing with a "decimaled " string.

Answer (score 4):

Get rid of the `^`, which matches the start of the string. You also need to escape `.`, since it's a regex meta character that matches any character (except newlines):

```
str.replaceAll("\\.0*$", "");
```

**Demo: http://ideone.com/RSJrO**

Comment: @Daniel ``str.replaceAll("\\.*0*$", "")`` works on "78.0000", "78.08" and "78.80000".

Comment: @RohanKandwal not sure if you noticed but this answer has only one `*` after the `0`, you have one before as well.