# Why does the look-behind expression in this regex not have an "obvious maximum length"?

Tags: java, regex

Given a string containing some number of square brackets and other characters, I want to find all closing square brackets preceded by an opening square bracket and some number of letters.
For instance, if the string is

> ] [abc] [123] abc]

I want to find only the second closing bracket.

The following regex

> (?<=[a-z]+)\]

will find me the second closing bracket, but also the last one:

> ] [abc**]** [123] abc**]**

Since I want to find only the first one, I make the obvious change to the regex...

> (?<=**\[**[a-z]+)\]

...and I get "Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length near index 11."

`\[` is only a single character, so it seems like the obvious maximum length should be 1 + whatever the obvious maximum length was of the look-behind group in the first expression. What gives?

---

**ETA:** It's not specific to the opening bracket.

> (?<=a[b-z]+)\]

gives me the same error. (Well, at index 12.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> \[ is only a single character, so it seems like the obvious maximum length should be 1 + whatever the obvious maximum length was of the look-behind group in the first expression. What gives?

That's the point, *"whatever the obvious maximum length was of the look-behind group in the first expression"*, is *not* obvious. A rule of fist is that you can't use `+` or `*` inside a look-behind. This is not only so for Java's regex engine, but for many more PCRE-flavored engines (even Perl's (v5.10) engine!).

You can do this with look-aheads however:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?=(\\[[a-z]+]))");
Matcher m = p.matcher("] [abc] [123] abc]");
while(m.find()) {
  System.out.println("Found a ']' before index: " + m.end(1));
}
```

*(I.e. a capture group inside a look ahead (!) which can be used to get the `end(...)` of the group)*

will print:

```
Found a ']' before index: 7
```

#### EDIT

And if you're interested in replacing such `]`'s, you could do something like this:

```
String s = "] [abc] [123] abc] [foo] bar]";
System.out.println(s);
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(\\[[a-z]+)]", "$1_"));
```

which will print:

```
] [abc] [123] abc] [foo] bar]
] [abc_ [123] abc] [foo_ bar]
```

Comment: @David, probably a recurring bug in the regex-API (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536915/regex-look-behind-without-obvious-maximum-length-in-java and http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6695369)

Comment: So am I right in thinking then that there isn't a regex that will get me just the bracket -- e.g., something I can use in `String.replace()`?

Comment: No, you're not right :). See my edit. (note that `replace(...)` doesn't use regex, its `replaceAll(...)` or `replaceFirst(...)`)

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say `replaceAll()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 "^[^\[]*\[[^\]]*?(\])"
```

is the group(1) what you want?