# Match the second substring using regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I need a regular expression that matches the second `"abc"` in `"abcasdabchjkabc"`.
I attempt to write code like this,

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=abc(.*?))abc");
```

but it throws a `java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException`:

```
Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length near index 11
(?<=abc(.*?))abc
           ^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1713)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.group0(Pattern.java:2488)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:1806)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1752)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1460)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1133)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:823)
```

Please show me the right one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want something like:

```
java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("(?<=abc.{1,99})abc");
```

It finds the second abc.

Comment: Yes! It's the one I'm looking for! Consider this string : `"abcabcdef"`, maybe `"(?<=abc.{0,99})abc"` is better.

Comment: If that is what you want 0 will work. The main point is that you have to use the curly braces syntax in a look-behind.

Comment: This is very poor solution, you are assuming that the `abc` in the look-behind is at most 99 characters away from the `abc` that you want to match.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use `*` or `+` in a look-behind assertion.

- [Why does the look-behind expression in this regex not have an "obvious maximum length"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7679393/139010)
- [Regex look-behind without obvious maximum length in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1536915/139010)

Do you actually want to match everything in between the two `abc`s?

```
Pattern.compile("abc(.*?)abc");
```

Or do you just want to check that there *are* two `abc`s?

```
Pattern.compile("abc.*?abc");
```

I don't see a *need* for lookbehind in either case.

Comment: I know the way to match the whole string, and it's enough when I need to replace a string. I just try to match the second `"abc"` only, to see whether regular expression can do this.

Answer (score 1):

A simple option is to match your pattern *twice*:

```
String input = "abcXYabcZRabc";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("abc");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

m.find(); // what to do when there is no match?
m.find(); // what to do when there is only one match?

System.out.println("Second match is between " + m.start() + " and " + m.end());
```

Working example: http://ideone.com/uVZL3j

Comment: This is also a nice approach. Thanks for telling me the usage of start() and end(). Just catch the `java.lang.IllegalStateException` if no match is available.