# Different regular expression result in Java SE and Android platform

Tags: java, android

I have the following **Java SE** code, which runs on PC

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // stringCommaPattern will change
    // ","abc,def","
    // to
    // ","abcdef","        
    Pattern stringCommaPattern = Pattern.compile("(\",\")|,(?=[^\"[,]]*\",\")");
    String data = "\"SAN\",\"Banco Santander, \",\"NYSE\"";
    System.out.println(data);
    final String result = stringCommaPattern.matcher(data).replaceAll("$1");
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

I'm getting expected result

```
"SAN","Banco Santander, ","NYSE"
"SAN","Banco Santander ","NYSE"
```

However, when comes to **Android**.

```
Pattern stringCommaPattern = Pattern.compile("(\",\")|,(?=[^\"[,]]*\",\")");
String data = "\"SAN\",\"Banco Santander, \",\"NYSE\"";
Log.i("CHEOK", data);
final String result = stringCommaPattern.matcher(data).replaceAll("$1");
Log.i("CHEOK", result);
```

I'm getting

```
"SAN","Banco Santander, ","NYSE"
"SAN","Banco Santandernull ","NYSE"
```

***Any suggestion and workaround, how I can make this code behaves same as it is at Java SE?***

---

### Additional Note :

Other patterns yield the same result as well. It seems that, **Android is using null string for unmatched group, and Java SE is using empty string for unmatched group.**

Take the following code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Used to remove the comma within an integer digit. The digit must be located
    // in between two string. Replaced with $1.
    //
    // digitPattern will change
    // ",100,000,"
    // to
    // ",100000,"        
    final Pattern digitPattern = Pattern.compile("(\",)|,(?=[\\d,]+,\")");
    String data = "\",100,000,000,\"";
    System.out.println(data);
    final String result = digitPattern.matcher(data).replaceAll("$1");
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

### Java SE

```
",100,000,000,"
",100000000,"
```

### Android

```
",100,000,000,"
",100null000null000,"
```

Comment: What version of android? There is a known bug in 2.1 with regex.

Comment: Edit: Confirmed error in android 3.2 (at least in the debugger).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a reason why, but as a workaround you could do the `appendReplacement` loop yourself rather than using `replaceAll`

```
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
Matcher m = digitPattern.matcher(data);
while(m.find()) {
  m.appendReplacement(result, (m.group(1) == null ? "" : "$1"));
}
m.appendTail(result);
```

This should work on both JavaSE and Android.

Or sidestep the problem entirely by changing the regex

```
Pattern commaNotBetweenQuotes = Pattern.compile("(?<!\"),(?!\")");
String result = commaNotBetweenQuotes.matcher(data).replaceAll("");
```

Here the regex matches just the commas you want to change, and not the ones you want to leave intact, so you can just replace them all with `""` with no need for capturing groups.

Comment: Thanks! I really love your solution for commaNotBetweenQuotes. I try to modify it to turn `" ,100,000,000, "` (space added) to `" ,100000000, "`. I use `Pattern.compile("(?<!\"\\s{0,0x7FFFFFFE}),(?!\\s{0,0x7FFFFFFE}\")")` according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536915/regex-look-behind-without-obvious-maximum-length-in-java, but rutime yields `java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Error in {min,max} interval near index 12`. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @CheokYanCheng I wasn't aware you could use hex literals in a bounded range operator.  Maybe try something like `\\s{0,10}` with a decimal number instead?

Comment: Thanks. I was able to use Pattern.compile("(?<!\"\\s{0," + (Integer.MAX_VALUE-1) + "}),(?!\\s{0," + (Integer.MAX_VALUE-1) + "}\")"); to resolve the problem. You are right. It is matter of hex literals. Note, I need to use -1, as 1 double quote already occupy the allowable space.