# Skip first occurance and split the string in Java

Tags: java, regex

I want to skip first occurrence if no of occurrence more than 4. For now I will get max of 5 number underscore occurrence. I need to produce the output A_B, C, D, E, F and I did using below code. I want better solution. Please check and let me know. Thanks in advance.

```
String key = "A_B_C_D_E_F";
int occurance = StringUtils.countOccurrencesOf(key, "_");
System.out.println(occurance);
String[] keyValues = null;
if(occurance == 5){
    key = key.replaceFirst("_", "-");
    keyValues = StringUtils.tokenizeToStringArray(key, "_");
    keyValues[0] = replaceOnce(keyValues[0], "-", "_");
}else{
    keyValues = StringUtils.tokenizeToStringArray(key, "_");
}

for(String keyValue : keyValues){
    System.out.println(keyValue);
}
```

Comment: Maybe this belongs on Code Review if it already he working.  Your stack isn't overflowing.

Comment: Have a look at [this demo](https://ideone.com/2W3PHE). I do not know why that works though.

Comment: Hi Wiktor , Thanks for your post . It will satisfy my need . I will check and understand how its works .

Comment: @Abdul check my answer, it is possible with a single split() call with a little trick. :-)

Comment: Now I even eliminated the trick. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex to split:

```
String s = "A_B_C_D_E_F";
String[] list = s.split("(?<=_[A-Z])_");
```

Output:

> [A_B, C, D, E, F]

The idea is to match only the `_` who are preceded by `"_[A-Z]"`, which effectively skips only the first one.

If the strings you are considering have a different format between the `"_"`, you have to replace `[A-Z]` by the appropriate regex

Comment: just as a sidenote, the only problem is that this doesn´t work anymore once the second character has an undefined length. But this works perfectly for the example.

Comment: @KevinEsche well obviously you have to change `[A-Z]` to match whatever is in between the `_`, but the idea would be exactly the same

Comment: Which will not work as you cannot use `*` or `+` in a look-behind in Java and your solution also does not respect the "skip if more than 4 are present" requirement.

Comment: @BjörnKautler Why not? I just tested `"(?<=_+[A-Z])_+"` and it works fine when I test it. So what do you mean?

Comment: Hm, actually I wonder now that this works, but try `"(?<=_+[A-Z]+)_+"`

Comment: It seems if you repeat anything but the first character in a look-behind with `+` or `*` you hit this problem.

Comment: @BjörnKautler yeah... `(?<=_+[A-Z]+)_+` does not compile.. I didn't know that. Why is that?

Comment: As far as I remember, to check the look-behind the Java regex engine has to save the content that was there before the actual thing the look-behind is attached to. If this is unbound, the Regex engine would potentially have to hold all input always and it would too likely overflow the memory at some point or something like that.

Comment: Here you can read more about the limitations of look-behind in various Regex libraries: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#limitbehind
From that description I still wonder that '*' and '+' work on the first character of the look-behind regex.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it is relatively "simple":

```
String str = "A_B_C_D_E_F_G";
String[] result = str.split("(?<!^[^_]*)_|_(?=(?:[^_]*_){0,3}[^_]*$)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

Here a version with comments for better understanding that can also be used as is:

```
String str = "A_B_C_D_E_F_G";
String[] result = str.split("(?x)                  # enable embedded comments \n"
                            + "                    # first alternative splits on all but the first underscore \n"
                            + "(?<!                # next character should not be preceded by \n"
                            + "    ^[^_]*          #     only non-underscores since beginning of input \n"
                            + ")                   # so this matches only if there was an underscore before \n"
                            + "_                   # underscore \n"
                            + "|                   # alternatively split if an underscore is followed by at most three more underscores to match the less than five underscores case \n"
                            + "_                   # underscore \n"
                            + "(?=                 # preceding character must be followed by \n"
                            + "    (?:[^_]*_){0,3} #     at most three groups of non-underscores and an underscore \n"
                            + "    [^_]*$          #     only more non-underscores until end of line \n"
                            + ")");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

Comment: Thanks for your support

Comment: You're welcome. I just wonder that you accepted a wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex based on `\G` and instead of splitting use matching:

```
String str = "A_B_C_D_E_F";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(^[^_]*_[^_]+|\\G[^_]+)(?:_|$)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
List<String> resultArr = new ArrayList<>();
while (m.find()) {
    resultArr.add( m.group(1) );
}
System.err.println(resultArr);
```

`\G` asserts position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match.

**Output:**

```
[A_B, C, D, E, F]
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fY4qL1/1)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it after the split.

```
public void test() {
    String key = "A_B_C_D_E_F";
    String[] parts = key.split("_");
    if (parts.length >= 5) {
        String[] newParts = new String[parts.length - 1];
        newParts[0] = parts[0] + "-" + parts[1];
        System.arraycopy(parts, 2, newParts, 1, parts.length - 2);
        parts = newParts;
    }
    System.out.println("parts = " + Arrays.toString(parts));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although Java does not say that officially, you can use `*` and `+` in the lookbehind as they are implemented as limiting quantifiers: `*` as `{0,0x7FFFFFFF}` and `+` as `{1,0x7FFFFFFF}` (see [Regex look-behind without obvious maximum length in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536915/regex-look-behind-without-obvious-maximum-length-in-java)). So, *if your strings are not too long*, you can use

```
String key = "A_B_C_D";       // => [A, B, C, D]
//String key = "A_B_C_D_E_F"; // => [A_B, C, D, E, F]
String[] res = null;
if (key.split("_").length > 4) {
    res = key.split("(?<!^[^_]*)_");
} else {
    res = key.split("_");
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res));
```

See the [JAVA demo](https://ideone.com/HOviG6)

**DISCLAIMER**: Since this is an exploit of the current Java 8 regex engine, the code may break in the future when the bug is fixed in Java.

Comment: This does not honour the requirement to only ignore the first underscore if there are more than 4 of them. My version does.

Comment: It does honour that now.

Comment: Yep, though it needs two split operations now, mine works with one. :-)

Comment: Cool. But your regex pattern is not that simple for laymen not like us :)

Comment: I added a commented version for better understanding. :-)