# Split the string based on number of occurrences in Java

Tags: java, regex

I want to split the values based on the number of occurrences.

- If the number of occurrences is 4
  e.g. key = `A-B-C-D`, the answer should be `A,B,C,D`
- If the number of occurrences is more than 4
  e.g. key = `A-B-C-D-E-F`, the answer should be `A-B-C,D,E,F`

Please find my attempt below:

```
String key = "A-B-C-D-E-F";
String[] res = key.split("(?<!^[^_]*)_");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res));
```

My output is `A-B,C,D,E,F` but my expectation is `A-B-C,D,E,F`

Similarly the number of occurrences varies based on usage. While splitting, I need to get maximum four values.

Please check and let me know about this.

Comment: `(?<!^[^_]*)_` won't work in Java because Lookbehind don't allow quantifiers.

Comment: @anubhava: [It works though](https://ideone.com/2W3PHE).

Comment: I'm surprised, even PCRE won't allow that.

Comment: java lookbehind does allow quantifiers, but only if the length of the string is finite afaik (like curly quantifier with upper bound); still i am surprised it works with star.

Comment: Right I know it works with `{0,999}` but with `*`, totally suprising

Comment: I guess we should ask @nhahtdh when he is online.

Comment: Even [the reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#limitbehind) confirms @anubhava's suspicion...

Comment: After pinging [nhahtdh](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/29834592#29834592) he could point me in the right direction. [This answer seems to explain our confusion...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1537370)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: This is a known issue in Java: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536915/regex-look-behind-without-obvious-maximum-length-in-java Java officially does not support variable length look-behind, but due to the way it implements `*` and the way it checks the length of the pattern in the look-behind, some cases are let through.

Comment: Is any other way to do it

Comment: Thanks for your support buddy :)

Comment: You cannot use the `split` like that in this case, since the lookbehind will become of unknown width.

Comment: i will try to find any other way to do it using regEx or i will use java code to achieve it :)

Comment: @Abdul: I hope you will review the previous questions and give credit to people who answered you.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew  :- I will credit to them  for their effort to support me ...

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew :- I checked and accepted their answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
//String key = "A-B-C-D";       // => [A, B, C, D]
String key = "A-B-C-D-E-F"; // => [A_B, C, D, E, F]
int keep = 3;
String[] res = key.split("-");
if (res.length > 4) {
    String first = String.join("-", Arrays.asList(res).subList(0, keep)); 
    List<String> lst = new ArrayList<>();
    lst.add(first);
    lst.addAll(Arrays.asList(res).subList(keep, res.length));
    res = new String[lst.size()];
    res = lst.toArray(res);
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res));
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/rYnVpg)

Basically, I suggest splitting first, and check how many elements we have. Then, just take as many first elements as we need to `keep`, and then combine this one with the rest.

Comment: @Braj: Thanks. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this regex way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input[] = { "A-B-C-D", "A-B-C-D-E-F-E-G", "AAAA-BBB-CCC-DD-EE", "BB-CC-DD-EE" };

    for (String str : input) {
        String output = str.replaceAll("(.*)-([\\w]+?)-([\\w]+?)-([\\w]+?)$", "$1 , $2 , $3 , $4");

        System.out.println("[" + str + "]\t\t\t=> [" + output + "]");
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
[A-B-C-D]               => [A , B , C , D]
[A-B-C-D-E-F-E-G]       => [A-B-C-D-E , F , E , G]
[AAAA-BBB-CCC-DD-EE]    => [AAAA-BBB , CCC , DD , EE]
[BB-CC-DD-EE]           => [BB , CC , DD , EE]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to have maximum four values after splitting, and you start splitting from the back, you can split by the following regex:

```
key.split("-(?!([^-]+-){3})");
```

The regex simply splits by a dash, as long as it can't find 3 dashes ahead. This results in the string being split at the last 3 dashes. Assuming that the input string does not end with dash, the resulting array will have exactly 4 values.