# How can one search for some text which is not part of a url?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Suppose the text to search is `pqr`.

```
"http://abc.zzz/pqr/xyz"      -> Should not match
"/pqr/"                       -> Should Match
"pqr"                         -> Should Match
"http://abc.zzz/pqr/pqr/"     -> Should not match
"http://abc.zzz/pqr/pqr/ pqr" -> Should match the last "pqr"
"www.pqr.zzz"                 -> Should not match
```

I tried using the following regex,

```
((?:(?:(?:https?|ftp|file|mailto):)|www)[^ ]+?)?(pqr)
```

I then looked for `group 1`, if it is empty then I was considering it as a match. But this fails for `http://abc.zzz/pqr/pqr/`

Any help here in detecting if the text to match is not part of a url?

The worst case I think is to detect all the urls first and then store the start and end indexes of the matched urls. Then try to match `pqr` and exclude all those which are part of the url. I was thinking if there is something that can be done better.

Comment: What do you need to match `pqr` for? Replace with something? The best way is to match the URL, and then the `pqr` (in an alternation group).

Comment: In my case `pqr` itself is a regular expression which might not always be a part of a url.

Comment: The worst case I think is to detect all the urls first and then store the start and end indexes of the matched urls. Then try to match `pqr` and exclude all those which are part of the url.

Comment: Yes, that is why I say: match a URL in one branch and capture it, and then  match the `pqr`. Something like `((?:https?|ftp|file|mailto)://\S*)|pqr` to replace with `$1` (if you want to remove `pqr`) or use a callback method to differentiate the actions.

Comment: Thanks for that. I was just hoping if there is something that can be done better here. I will go for the same solution if thats the only way to do it.

Comment: Well, if you are using .NET regex, you can use [`(?<!(?:https?|ftp|file|mailto)://(?:www\.)?\S*)(?<!\bwww\.)pqr`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c!(%3f%3ahttps%3f%7cftp%7cfile%7cmailto)%3a%2f%2f(%3f%3awww%5c.)%3f%5cS*)(%3f%3c!%5cbwww%5c.)pqr&i=http%3a%2f%2fabc.zzz%2fpqr%2fxyz%0d%0a+-%3e+Should+not+match%0d%0a%2fpqr%2f%0d%0a+-%3e+Should+Match%0d%0apqr%0d%0a+-%3e+Should+Match%0d%0ahttp%3a%2f%2fabc.zzz%2fpqr%2fpqr%2f%0d%0a+-%3e+Should+not+match%0d%0ahttp%3a%2f%2fabc.zzz%2fpqr%2fpqr%2f+pqr%0d%0a+-%3e+Should+match+the+last+%22pqr%22%0d%0awww.pqr.zzz%0d%0a+-%3e+Should+not+match).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm actually using Java. But thanks a lot, I never knew that we can quantifiers in lookbehinds in java regex. You can post your solution as an answer. Just a minor correction that there is no `//` in `mailto:` url scheme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking into account you are using Java, you can leverage the *constrained-width lookbehind* that Java regex engine supports. It means you can use `{n,m}` limiting quantifier in the pattern. Right now, [Java 8 supports even `*` and `+` quantifiers inside a lookbehind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536915/regex-look-behind-without-obvious-maximum-length-in-java) (although unofficially), but this is a bug and is likely to be fixed in the next version. Thus, you may use some range, say `0 to 1000` (as the link is not likely to contain more than 1K symbols, but you may adjust it to the factual situation):

```
 (?<!(?:(?:https?|ftp|file)://|mailto:)(?:www\.)?\S{0,1000})(?<!\bwww\.\S{0,1000})pqr
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c!(%3f%3a(%3f%3ahttps%3f%7cftp%7cfile)%3a%2f%2f%7cmailto%3a)(%3f%3awww%5c.)%3f%5cS%7b0%2c1000%7d)(%3f%3c!%5cbwww%5c.%5cS%7b0%2c1000%7d)pqr&i=http%3a%2f%2fabc.zzz%2fpqr%2fxyz%0d%0a+-%3e+Should+not+match%0d%0a%2fpqr%2f%0d%0a+-%3e+Should+Match%0d%0apqr%0d%0a+-%3e+Should+Match%0d%0ahttp%3a%2f%2fabc.zzz%2fpqr%2fpqr%2f%0d%0a+-%3e+Should+not+match%0d%0ahttp%3a%2f%2fabc.zzz%2fpqr%2fpqr%2f+pqr%0d%0a+-%3e+Should+match+the+last+%22pqr%22%0d%0awww.pqr.zzz%0d%0awww.new.pqr.zzz%0d%0a+-%3e+Should+not+match%0d%0amailto%3akowalski%40pqr.com.pl)

The first lookbehind `(?<!(?:(?:https?|ftp|file)://|mailto:)(?:www\.)?\S{0,1000})` will check if the `pqr` is not preceded with a full URL, and `(?<!\bwww\.\S{0,1000})` lookbehind will check if the `pqr` is not preceded with `www.`.