# Split string by repeatable delimiter in Java/Kotlin

Tags: java, regex, kotlin

I am splitting a string by a repeatable delimiter, and am also intended to keep the delimiters as well.

```kotlin
val str = "xxoooooooxxoxoxooooo"
val reg = Regex("(?<=x+)|(?=x+)")
var list = str.split(reg)
println(list)
```

The output is `[, x, x, ooooooo, x, x, o, x, o, x, ooooo]`, though I would like to get

`[xx, ooooooo, xx, o, x, o, x, ooooo]`

Comment: why don't you just match all [`x+|o+`](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyd3mtaar)

Comment: @bobblebubble One reason is that if the input string contains not only `x` and `o`, it would not work. However, the string is the question only contains `x` and `o`, so the pattern will work for this string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm commenting on the sample string and the question, anything else is just your guess. If this is the task, I think using lookarounds is overcomplicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, it is not correct to use `+` quantifier inside a lookbehind in Java's regex patterns, this is not a documented supported feature. It does not throw exception because internally [it is translated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1537370/3832970) into `{1,0x7FFFFFFF}` and Java's regex supports constrained-width lookbehind patterns. However, this quantifier in both the lookbehind and lookahead makes no difference as these are non-consuming patterns, and the regex engine still checks *each position* inside a string for a pattern match.

You can use

```kotlin
(?<=x)(?=o)|(?<=o)(?=x)
```

See a [Kotlin demo](https://rextester.com/JVAZO13332):

```kotlin
val str = "xxoooooooxxoxoxooooo"
val reg = Regex("(?<=x)(?=o)|(?<=o)(?=x)")
var list = str.split(reg)
println(list) 
// => [xx, ooooooo, xx, o, x, o, x, ooooo]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
val str = "xxoooooooxxoxoxooooo"
val reg =  Regex("o+|x+").findAll(str).map { it.value }.toList()
println(reg)
//[xx, ooooooo, xx, o, x, o, x, ooooo]
```